# Why does tr "\oo" " " not replace the "\" character?

Tags: command-line, tr

I ran `echo "\oo" | tr "\oo" " "`, and the output is:

```
\
```

`\o` is not a special character, like `\n`, so why is the `\` not converted into a space too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `\o` is not a special character, like `\n`, so why is the `\` not converted into a space too?

Because the shell and GNU tr appear to deal with unknown backslash sequences differently.

When the shell sees `"\oo"`, it leaves the backslash as-is (I think that's the required standard behaviour). But when `tr` consequently gets `\oo` as its first argument, it interprets the `\o` as just `o`. Busybox's `tr` deals with this differently, this prints only spaces `echo "\oo" | busybox tr "\oo" "  "`.

Conclusion, don't rely on undefined backslash sequences, but escape the backslashes when they are meant to be taken literally.

E.g. use `echo '\oo' | tr '\\o' '  '` instead. (The single quotes protect the backslash from the shell, the second backslash escapes the other for `tr`.)

Answer (score 1):

This question is essentially "how do you escape the escape '\' char?"

Answer: The same way you escape all other chars.

```
$ echo "\oo" | tr "\oo" " "
\ 

$ echo "\oo" | tr "\\oo" " "
\ 
 
$ echo "\oo" | tr "\\\oo" " "
 (blank output)
```

Comment: I see, so does the  \ in `echo "\oo" | tr "\oo" " "` not have a meaning since you need to do \\ to replace the \ with a space?

Comment: Yes, it has a meaning: It's the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). Whole wikipedia page on the topic.